# TypeError: Cannot read property 'receiver_id' of undefined

Tags: javascript, android, angularjs, node.js

This funcion is to give notifications to the user when someone sends a request to him
I am creating a messaging app for learning purposs and am not able to resolve the issue. the firebase console keeps giving the error : firebase functions

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'receiver_id' of undefined
   at exports.sendNotification.functions.database.ref.onWrite.event 
(/user_code/index.js:9:36)
at Object.<anonymous> (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/cloud- 
   functions.js:112:27)
    at next (native)
at /user_code/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/cloud-functions.js:28:71
at __awaiter (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/cloud- 
   functions.js:24:12)
at cloudFunction (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/cloud- 
   functions.js:82:36)
at /var/tmp/worker/worker.js:728:24
    at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:135:7)
```

----- My code is -----

```
'use strict'

const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);
exports.sendNotification = 
functions.database.ref('/Notifications/{receiver_id}/{notification_id}')
        .onWrite(event => 
       {
           const receiver_id = event.params.receiver_id;
        console.log('We ahve a notification to send to : ', receiver_id);
        if(!event.data.val())
        {return console.log('Notification has been deleted', notification_id);}
    const DeviceToken = admin.database().ref(`/users/${receiver_id}/device_token`).once(value);
    return DeviceToken.then(result =>
    {
        const token_id=result.val();
        const payload={
            notification:
            {
                title : "Friend Request",
                body : "you have recived a new friend request",
                icon : "default"
            }
        };
        return admin.messaging().sendToDevice(token_id,payload)
            .then(response =>
            {
                return console.log('This is notification');
            });
        });
    });
```

Comment: what do you have inside of `event` in `onWrite`? The error message is telling you that `params` is undefined in `event.params.received_id`

Answer (score 0):

`params` are provided by the [2nd parameter](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/functions.database.RefBuilder#onWrite) of the `onWrite` callback function.

```
.onWrite((snapshot, context) => {
  const receiver_id = context.params.receiver_id;
});
```

Comment: now it returns another error
`TypeError: Cannot read property 'val' of undefined
    at exports.sendNotification.functions.database.ref.onWrite `